Create a route event layer in ArcGIS Pro
I'm forced to migrate from ArcMap to ArcGIS Pro. One of the features I use the most is Linear Referencing and showing points along routes.
In ArcMap you can create your routes, and use the find function to locate individual points along these routes. Then you just right click on event table there is an option to display route events as a graphic.
In ArcGIS Pro I have used the make route event layer tool from a CSV table, then tried the locate features tool. I get the 000666 error (no OID). My original CSV does contain any geometry, just a distance along the route, so I'm guessing that this is the issue.
It was a simple process in ArcMap, now it seems impossible in ArcGIS Pro.
Any ideas?

Looks like the third paragraph is missing "n't" after "does".

Try importing your CSV into a file geodatabase so it does create an ObjectID field then use that table to construct your event layer? So what was once a nice easy 1-step processing in arcmap is now an annoying 2-step process.

Thanks Hornbydd, that did the trick.
